# Linq to SQL: Can a stored proc eager load an entire entity graph including child entities?

Tags: linq-to-sql, stored-procedures

Just like the title says, I'm looking to eager load a whole entity graph with a number of 1-1 child entities.  It seems like stored procedure can only load the parent entity, and then LINQ uses lazy loading to populate the child entities as they are accessed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct, I do not think you can easily eager load `EntityRef` and `EntitySet` out-of-band from a proc. If you want to eager load, you need to use the "approved" way, with the hints on the context.

I suspect you could design a monster object, load it up with ExecuteQuery and then split it up into your graph, but that would skip the identity map which would lead to other issues.